# Magento 2.3.4 Undefined index: decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default 0

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, ssh

I am trying to install a Reward Point Extension from MagePlaza, after i upload the files and enable the module via SSH, My site crashes.

After the extension install I run bin/magento setup:upgrade and get this message:

```
Undefined index: decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default 0 in/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SchemaListener.php on line 137
```

I get this error message on my site:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magestore_Rewardpoints schema: current version - none, required version - 1.2.0.5
Magestore_Rewardpoints data: current version - none, required version - 1.2.0.5

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magestore_Rewardpoints schema: current version - none, required version - 1.2.0.5
Magestore_Rewardpoints data: current version - none, required version - 1.2.0.5
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007f23423700000000495edb1c#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#2 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000007f23439900000000495edb1c#, &Closure#000000007f2343f800000000495edb1c#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007f23423700000000495edb1c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007f23423700000000495edb1c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007f23423700000000495edb1c#), array(array('page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'), array('front-controller...'), 'requestPreproces...')) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007f23423700000000495edb1c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000007f23424100000000495edb1c#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: this module name remove form database `setup_module` table and run `php bin/magento s:up`

Comment: there is nothing in the `setup_module` table for this extension.

Comment: in `setup_module` table find this `Magestore_Rewardpoints` and check table last page ...